# Where is this extra space coming from?

Tags: html, css, position, spacing

My Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/aFJfs

It has something to do with the `.email-tip-icon` and the `tip-message` because when I commented them out the spacing goes away. Each one seems to add more spacing... However I have the both the `margin` and `padding` set to `0`

The extra spacing is between the **email** input field and the **first name** input field

[image]

Comment: Your codepen is blank.

Comment: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/AyvgG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making them position absolute and update accordingly.
this should work:

```
#register-form .email-tip-icon, #register-form .password-tip-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 340px;
    z-index: 2;
    clear: both;
    background: red;
    top: 20px;
    }
    #register-form .tip-message {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 374px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-indent: 10px;
    background: url(http://leongaban.com/_projects/whoat/_HTML/img/gray-tip-triangle.png) no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 25px;
    }
```

Comment: Right, elements that are relatively positioned still occupy the space they originated from.

Comment: Thanks! This actually lead me to the real issue, which I still don't know exactly why it's an issue. Anyways my tip message needed to have position absolute, I guess position relative adds that invisible space somewhere

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea where this comes from, but here is an easy fix:

```
#register-email{
    margin-bottom:-10px !important;
}
#register-firstname{
    margin-top:-40px !important
}
```

**http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/AyvgG**

Comment: Uhm yeah that is fixing my problem, can you take a look at this? I corrected my form with your fix (changed the numbers slightly) then I hide the first 'tip message' the tip message actually comes up when you hover over the question. Now once I put a display:none on the tip message my spacing is over correct, but correct once the tip shows up on rollover. Some box issue? http://leongaban.com/_projects/whoat/_HTML/login/test.html

Comment: @Leon I see that. The problem is with that tooltip box then. May I suggest you to use `jQuery`'s `.tooltip()` function if you already use the library in your code?
----------------------
Could the downvoters express themself please?

Comment: You're arbitrarily modifying the margins without understanding what's causing the problem in the first place.  See Mark's answer, there was an element that was relatively positioned still taking up its original space.